# Generic code for handling Azure Tables concurrency conflicts?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-storage

I'm looking at doing some updates into Azure Storage Tables. I want to use the optimistic concurrency mechanism properly. It seems like you'd need to do something like:

1. Load row to update, possibly retrying failures
2. Apply updates to row
3. Save row, possibly retrying network errors

   1. If there is a concurrency conflict, reload the data (possibly retrying failures) and attempt to save again (possible retrying failures)

Is there some generic class or code sample that handles this? I can code it up, but I have to imagine someone has already invented this particular wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone invented this wheel they're not talking, so I went off and (re)invented it myself. This is intentionally very generic, more of a skeleton than a finished product. It's basically just the algorithm I outlined above. The caller has to wire in delegates to do the actual loading, updating and saving of the data. There is basic retry logic built in, but I would recommend overriding those functions with something more robust.

I believe this will work with tables or BLOBs, and single entities or batches, though I've only actually tried it with single-entity table updates.

Any comments, suggestions, improvements, etc would be appreciated.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient;
using System.Net;

namespace SepiaLabs.Azure
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt to write an update to storage while using optimistic concurrency.
    /// Implements a basic state machine. Data will be fetched (with retries), then mutated, then updated (with retries, and possibly refetching & remutating). 
    /// Clients may pass in a state object with relevant information. eg, a TableServiceContext object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This object natively implements a very basic retry strategy. 
    /// Clients may want to subclass it and override the ShouldRetryRetrieval() and ShouldRetryPersist() functions to implement more advanced retry strategies. 
    /// 
    /// This class intentionally avoids checking if the row is present before updating it. This is so callers may throw custom exceptions, or attempt to insert the row instead ("upsert" style interaction)
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="RowType">The type of data that will be read and updated. Though it is called RowType for clarity, you could manipulate a collection of rows.</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="StateObjectType">The type of the user-supplied state object</typeparam>
    public class AzureDataUpdate<RowType, StateObjectType>
        where RowType : class
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Function to retrieve the data that will be updated. 
        /// This function will be called at least once. It will also be called any time a concurrency update conflict occurs. 
        /// </summary>
        public delegate RowType DataRetriever(StateObjectType stateObj);

        /// <summary>
        /// Function to apply the desired changes to the data.
        /// This will be called after each time the DataRetriever function is called. 
        /// If you are using a TableServiceContext with MergeOption.PreserveChanges set, this function can be a no-op after the first call
        /// </summary>
        public delegate void DataMutator(RowType data, StateObjectType stateObj);

        /// <summary>
        /// Function to persist the modified data. The may be called multiple times. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data"></param>
        /// <param name="stateObj"></param>
        public delegate void DataPersister(RowType data, StateObjectType stateObj);

        public DataRetriever RetrieverFunction { get; set; }
        public DataMutator MutatorFunction { get; set; }
        public DataPersister PersisterFunction { get; set; }

        public AzureDataUpdate()
        {
        }

        public AzureDataUpdate(DataRetriever retrievalFunc, DataMutator mutatorFunc, DataPersister persisterFunc)
        {
            this.RetrieverFunction = retrievalFunc;
            this.MutatorFunction = mutatorFunc;
            this.PersisterFunction = persisterFunc;
        }

        public RowType Execute(StateObjectType userState)
        {
            if (RetrieverFunction == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must provide a data retriever function before executing");
            }
            else if (MutatorFunction == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must provide a data mutator function before executing");
            }
            else if (PersisterFunction == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must provide a data persister function before executing");
            }

            //Retrieve and modify data
            RowType data = this.DoRetrieve(userState);

            //Call the mutator function. 
            MutatorFunction(data, userState);

            //persist changes
            int attemptNumber = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                bool isPreconditionFailedResponse = false;

                try
                {
                    PersisterFunction(data, userState);
                    return data; //return the mutated data
                }
                catch (DataServiceRequestException dsre)
                {
                    DataServiceResponse resp = dsre.Response;

                    int statusCode = -1;
                    if (resp.IsBatchResponse)
                    {
                        statusCode = resp.BatchStatusCode;
                    }
                    else if (resp.Any())
                    {
                        statusCode = resp.First().StatusCode;
                    }

                    isPreconditionFailedResponse = (statusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed);
                    if (!ShouldRetryPersist(attemptNumber, dsre, isPreconditionFailedResponse, userState))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                catch (DataServiceClientException dsce)
                {
                    isPreconditionFailedResponse = (dsce.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed);
                    if (!ShouldRetryPersist(attemptNumber, dsce, isPreconditionFailedResponse, userState))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                catch (StorageClientException sce)
                {
                    isPreconditionFailedResponse = (sce.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed);
                    if (!ShouldRetryPersist(attemptNumber, sce, isPreconditionFailedResponse, userState))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (!ShouldRetryPersist(attemptNumber, ex, false, userState))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                if (isPreconditionFailedResponse)
                {
                    //Refetch the data, re-apply the mutator
                    data = DoRetrieve(userState);
                    MutatorFunction(data, userState);
                }

                attemptNumber++;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve the data to be updated, possibly with retries
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userState">The UserState for this operation</param>
        private RowType DoRetrieve(StateObjectType userState)
        {
            int attemptNumber = 1;

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    return RetrieverFunction(userState);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (!ShouldRetryRetrieval(attemptNumber, ex, userState))
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                attemptNumber++;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determine whether a data retrieval should be retried. 
        /// Implements a simplistic, constant wait time strategy. Users may override to provide a more complex implementation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attemptNumber">What number attempt is this. </param>
        /// <param name="ex">The exception that was caught</param>
        /// <param name="userState">The user-supplied state object for this operation</param>
        /// <returns>True to attempt the retrieval again, false to abort the retrieval and fail the update attempt</returns>
        protected virtual bool ShouldRetryRetrieval(int attemptNumber, Exception ex, StateObjectType userState)
        {
            //Simple, basic retry strategy - try 3 times, sleep for 1000msec each time
            if (attemptNumber < 3)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Determine whether a data update should be retried. If the <paramref name="isPreconditionFailed"/> param is true, 
        /// then the retrieval and mutation process will be repeated as well
        /// Implements a simplistic, constant wait time strategy. Users may override to provide a more complex implementation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="attemptNumber">What number attempt is this. </param>
        /// <param name="ex">The exception that was caught</param>
        /// <param name="userState">The user-supplied state object for this operation</param>
        /// <param name="isPreconditionFailedResponse">Indicates whether the exception is a PreconditionFailed response. ie, an optimistic concurrency failure</param>
        /// <returns>True to attempt the update again, false to abort the retrieval and fail the update attempt</returns>
        protected virtual bool ShouldRetryPersist(int attemptNumber, Exception ex, bool isPreconditionFailedResponse, StateObjectType userState)
        {
            if (isPreconditionFailedResponse)
            {
                return true; //retry immediately
            }
            else
            {
                //For other failures, wait to retry
                //Simple, basic retry strategy - try 3 times, sleep for 1000msec each time
                if (attemptNumber < 3)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```