# Using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServicesContext and detecting concurrency update conflicts

Tags: .net, azure-table-storage, optimistic-concurrency

The problem is that some classes (DataServiceClientException / DataServiceRequestException / DataServiceResponse) exist in both System.Data.Services.Client.dll and Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll. The simple approach would be to [use only one of those libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773011/microsoft-data-services-client-dll-vs-system-data-services-client-dll). Unfortunately:

- System.Data.Services.Client.dll cannot be removed because it is required for using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServicesContext
- Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll is required for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServicesContext on Azure.

Normally these two libraries work fine together. However, implementing the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367735/generic-code-for-handling-azure-tables-concurrency-conflicts/9400267#9400267) to detect concurrency conflicts results in errors:

```
Error   1   The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequestException' exists in both 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0\bin\.NETFramework\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll' and 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'
Error   2   The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceResponse' exists in both 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0\bin\.NETFramework\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll' and 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'
Error   3   The type 'System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException' exists in both 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft WCF Data Services\5.0\bin\.NETFramework\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll' and 'C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.Services.Client.dll'
```

because `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException`, `DataServiceRequestException`, and `DataServiceResponse` classes cannot be accessed as they exist in both libraries. How does one detect concurrency update conflicts while using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServicesContext?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use C#'s [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx) feature.

1. Expand the references section of your project.
2. Right click on System.Data.Services.Client and choose properties.
3. Change Aliases from "global" to "system" or something else.

and the project builds fine.